# Захват видео и запись

Tags: аудио, ffmpeg, ubuntu

Решил оцифровать старые видеозаписи на кассетах. `dazzle` определяется как `./dev/video0` .

```
ffmpeg -an -f video4linux2 -i /dev/video0 -r 3 -s 320x240 -y out.mpg
```

Небольшой пример. Звук писать лучше отдельно на свою звуковую карточку.Всё равно придется синжронизировать. Как записать в цвете? Пишет только в черно-беломварианте.

Где дописать или доставить какой пакет что-бы можно было записать в цвете .Захват пробовал делать с видеомагнитофона через usb Dazzle HW-SET DVC100Rew.1.1 Pinnacle .Да забыл , запись с веб камеры по такой-же команде получилась в цвете.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего вы не выставили режим PAL/NTSC. Если пишите с камеры/видеомагнитофона через композитный вход (колокольчики) вероятен режим PAL_B, если используете провод S-Video — NTSC_M